# Flutter macos configuration - flutter folder in .gtignore?

Tags: flutter, macos, gitignore, xcconfig

in macos configuration (project_flutter/macos/Runner/Configs), we have xcconfig files that refer to other files that are in the folder : project_flutter/macos/Flutter.

Example:
Project_flutter/macos/Runner/Configs/Release.xcconfig

```
#include "../../Flutter/Flutter-Release.xcconfig"
#include "Warnings.xcconfig"
```

And Project_flutter/macos/Flutter/Flutter-Release.xcconfig is in the gtignore

```
**/macos/Flutter/Flutter-Release.xcconfig
```

Could you precise me please, if Flutter-Release.xcconfig should be in gtignore ? (and ephemeral folder too ?)

Have you a example of gtignore for flutter macos configuration

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the gitignore in `./macos` flutter generates when adding macos support:

```
# Flutter-related
**/Flutter/ephemeral/
**/Pods/

# Xcode-related
**/dgph
**/xcuserdata/
```